# Execute Jquery when a specific page in my plugin is loading

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, jquery, ajax

I am building a plugin and I would like to be able to hide the wordpress admin side menu and top bar when a specific page is shown(or menu item clicked)?

Should I call the jquery directly as a script on the plugin page's code, or is there a way I can execute the jquery when the page is loading, or menu item is clicked from a hooked function with ajax or something similar? Here is the jquery I wan't to run:

```
$("#wpadminbar, #adminmenuwrap").hide();
```

Comment: How are you **enqueueing** your Plugin's script(s)? Please post all relevant code, in context.

Comment: If all you're using is .hide() then maybe it makes sense to just do it via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the screen id on the screen (or page) in question using [get_current_screen()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)

```
get_current_screen()->id
```

Then, hook into it with the following:

```
function my_script_function() {
    if ( strpos( get_current_screen()->id, 'screen_id' ) !== false ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_javascript_handle', 'path/to/my/script.js', 'jquery', '1.0' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_script_function' );
```

This will enqueue your script properly in the WordPress system along with jQuery core (just in case it isn't already there).

http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/ has a good overview of using jQuery in WordPress. Please note that by default though you can't use *$* to call jQuery as it is in safe mode (the article will show you how to change it from having to use *jQuery*.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this works exactly as needed. I appreciate it.